# IKEV2 tunnel not getting created

Tags: security, ipsec

Getting bellow error message while trying to ping.

> Feb 12 17:51:11.383 IST: IKEv2-INTERNAL:Processing an item off the pak
>   queue
>
> Feb 12 17:51:11.384 IST: IKEv2-INTERNAL:Couldn't find matching SA Feb
>   12 17:51:11.386 IST: IKEv2-ERROR:Couldn't find matching SA: Detected
>   an invalid IKE SPI Feb 12 17:51:11.388 IST: IKEv2-ERROR:: A supplied
>   parameter is incorrect Feb 12 17:51:13.048 IST: IKEv2-INTERNAL:Got a
>   packet from dispatcher

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are going to need some more information in order to help you with this. What device is the VPN server? What device is the VPN client? What are the settings on each end. We need full details. It says you supplied an incorrect parameter so we need to see all the parameters.

Comment: Hi , I am trying to make the IPsec tunnel between 2 wireless controllers.

Comment: Have found the issue and resolved it as well . There was a Vlan issue

Comment: Please write up the solution as an aswer to your own question. Then accept your answer as correct. This will earn you reputation on this site and close this issue out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Topology was 2 wireless controller connected via switch and has 2 vlans each , lets say vlan 96 and vlan 97.

SVI for controller 1 :

9.2.96.51 and 9.2.97.12

SVI for controller 2:

9.2.96.12 and 9.2.97.51

I was forming mapping the ipsec crypto map with :

9.2.96.51(controller1) with 9.2.97.51(controller2)

Now when trying to make the IKEV2 tunnel to come up , started ping from controller1 to controller 2 and the packet is getting dropped and tunnel not forming.

Now here whats happening was instead of going to the other VLAN. packet is going to the same VLAN due to which tunnel not getting formed.

Means Packet should go from vlan 96 to vlan 97 but as both vlans are present . so pinging from VLAN 96 of controller 1 goes to VLAn 96 of controller2 instead VLAN 97.

So just shut down the other VLAN and then tried to ping and it worked.